# VBA Create An Array Variable With Uniform Values

Tags: arrays, vba

Is there a way to create an array variable with uniform entries without using a loop?  For example, to create an array variable with 25 entries I could do the following:

```
Dim myarray(1 to 25) as String

For n = 1 to 25
    myarray(n) = "Hello"
Next n
```

This would get the job done, but I am looking for a way to do that in one fell swoop.

Comment: You mean: `Dim vArr As Variant: vArr=Array("one", "two", .. "twenty nine"...)` ?

Comment: Not quite.  I'd like it to have all the same value like:  `Dim vArr as Variant: vArr=Array("one","one", .. "one"...)`

Comment: Whenever a loop is the most obvious approach it's usually the best approach.  If you want to do this multiple times then wrap it up in a function.